# How to assign the second recurring element from another vectors zero values?

Tags: arrays, matlab

For example I have a one vector:

```
y = [21 19 15 17 18 19 25 36 48 19 19]'
```

In y vector I have a recurring element 19. And I should another vector, in which all elements are equal to one, but if the element has already met for the second time or greater, then assign it a value of zero:

```
l = [1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]'
```

**How to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second output of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.unique.html) tells you when a number appears for the first time; that is, which positions in the result should be set to `1`:

```
y = [21 19 15 17 18 19 25 36 48 19 19]';
[~ ,v] = unique(y, 'stable');
l = zeros(size(y));
l(v) = 1;
```

---

Another approach, using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), is as follows. This is less efficient because it computes an intermediate *N*×*N* matrix, where *N* is the size of the input:

```
y = [21 19 15 17 18 19 25 36 48 19 19]';
l = ~any(triu(y==y.', 1), 1).';
```

Comment: Sorry,  for my mistake... Everything works great!